# Change web browser and text message app in Huawei P30 Lite

Tags: huawei, default-applications, navigation-bar

On my Huamei P30 Lite, I am using Firefox as a web browser app and Silence as text message app. Although I changed the default app in the settings, I am not able to change the app in the bottom navigation bar, see circled icons in the attached image. I did it on my previous phones (LG GT540, LG Optimus L5 II and Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge). How can I change those apps?

[image]

Comment: Try press- holding it for a few seconds and you may be able to move or delete as with many launchers. Or simply Uninstall those default apps (if permitted). Last resort change to a launcher like Nova or any other which doesn't force default icons to be displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days, I finally figured this out. Long press on the icon only display a new menu. In order to change it, I pressed another upper icon, e.g. Play Store, then, dragged this icon into the lower bar, e.g. beside Chrome. Only then, one is able to drag icons away from the lower icon bar.